# Detect XML or SGML parser used in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, parsing, xhtml

HTML is a subset of SGML.

XHTML is a subset of XML.

Both use separate parsers.

Presuming an HTML document is correctly served as `text/html` and an XHTML application is correctly served as `application/xhtml+xml` is it possible to detect which parser is used to render the page and if so how?

- I do understand *exactly* what I am asking. Please do not insist on asking why I want to do this.
- I'd rather not receive answers suggesting that I do not use one language or the other. This is to avoid debate and help produce an answer I can use.

Comment: Those are probably not your only options - browsers are likely to have at least one other mode for tag soup.

Comment: Also, why do you want to do this? It really would seem that just using well formed documents of one type would suffice.

Comment: HTML is no longer an application of SGML. The current HTML standard defines different parsing rules... Quote: "*Also, since neither of the two authoring formats defined in this specification are applications of SGML, a validating SGML system cannot constitute a conformance checker either.*" from here: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/infrastructure.html#conformance-checkers

Comment: Further proof: "*For compatibility with existing content and prior specifications, this specification describes two authoring formats: one based on XML (referred to as the XHTML syntax), and one using a **custom format inspired by SGML** (referred to as the HTML syntax)*"

Comment: "ask for a clarification *first* if you do not understand" I don't understand why you have a "JavaScript:" title prefix when we have a [javascript] tag.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn: I don't understand why you didn't [edit] to remove the tag from the title.

Comment: 1.) When I search I use the language name (e.g. javascript detect xyz) which makes it easier for people to find. 2.) Three up-votes in less than an hour when this question has had less then a hundred views in several months is highly suspicious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This is a replacement for my original answer. My original idea was to exploit differences in the behaviour of innerHTML. Although it worked fine in IE9, Firefox and Chrome, it turned out that it failed in Opera, which appears to use an HTML parser for innerHTML even for pages served as `application/xhtml+xml`]

---

There's not too many ways to tell XML documents apart from HTML documents. One way however, is to exploit the case handling differences between HTML and XML.

In particular, the behaviour of [Element.tagName](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#dom-element-tagname) differs. In an HTML parsed document, the element name will be coerced to upper case for `tagName` whereas in an XML parsed document it won't be. So we can test `document.createElement("div").tagName == "DIV"` which will give a different result depending on how the document was parsed.

See this test case:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
    <head>      
        <title>Test Case</title>
        <script>
            window.onload = function() {
              document.getElementById("result")
                .appendChild(document.createTextNode(
                  (document.createElement("div").tagName == "DIV") 
                    ? "HTML parser" : "XML parser"));
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="result"></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

See it in action:

- HTML parse: http://www.alohci.net/text/html/parserdetect1.htm.ashx
- XML parse:    http://www.alohci.net/application/xhtml+xml/parserdetect1.htm.ashx

Comment: Looks like it's on-topic though haven't even had a chance to get online until just now; will look in to this tomorrow and let you know how it works, thanks!

Comment: Excellent! I tested it out and appreciate your recant of innerHTML (of which I absolutely dislike since it does not work properly with the DOM). Accepted as answer and thumbed it up, thank you!