# Is it better to check tagName or instanceof HTMLAnchorElement

Tags: javascript, dom

If I want to check that a particular DOM node is an anchor element, which option would be safer and faster?

By safer I'm looking to see which is better supported by older browsers such as IE6-8.

I'm assuming there won't be much of a speed difference but if a function is doing this check while traversing a DOM tree it might save a few milliseconds.

Comment: Both are supported pretty much since the beginning of time, and even while traversing the DOM tree, the big operation is querying/changing for DOM nodes, once you have a DOM node in memory, both methods will be ± the same performance-wise.

Comment: milliseconds => microseconds

Comment: You generally see `element.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A"` more often than instanceof, not sure why, the difference should be minuscule? I personlly generally use the former.

Comment: @adeneo, wouldn't `element.tagName` already be uppercase?

Comment: @RickHitchcock - sure would in all current browsers at least, but doesn't hurt to make sure, it's also quite common in cases like this to compare the returned string insensitive, as it's so easy to do.

Comment: @adeneo I think that's the spec.

Comment: @torazaburo - it is, for HTML5 at least. For imported XML, including the older XHTML doctypes, it returns the tagname as written, i.e. it could be lowercase. That's why it was so common to force case, upper or lower, quite a few years back, and even if it shouldn't be needed today, many developers just do it out of old habit I suppose.

Comment: @adeneo - It's about mime type, not doctype, and yes it can be used today with HTML5. It's even a good way to [tell documents created by an HTML parser and documents created using an XHTML parser apart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8522951/javascript-detect-parser-used-xml-or-sgml/8531431#8531431)

Comment: @Alohci - Didn't know that, I think? It's been a long time since the case of tagnames was an issue, but you're probably right, anything delivered with the mime type of `text/xml` probably returns tagnames as written in the markup

Comment: Seems `tagName` is faster than `instanceof`, \
base on https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/6769/0/tagname-vs-instanceof . \
=> https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/ShowResult/398590 \
`instanceof x 1,821,271 ops/sec ±0.84% (65 runs sampled) \
tagName x 2,156,227 ops/sec ±1.94% (54 runs sampled)`

Answer (score -1):

Using javascript, proc resources are not a priority in 99% cases.
If you have to check the tagName, you better use tagName which is explicitly exposed to you.

And for me, instanceof is much longer because you have to check the type of the prototype, tagName is a property already set.

Comment: What do you mean by "proc resources are not a priority in 99% cases"?